# Are @After and @AfterClass guaranteed to run

Tags: java, junit

Are @After and @AfterClass methods guaranteed to run even if there is a serious error or exception?

Comment: what do you mean by "serious" - just some exception, or something really serious like out of memory?

Comment: Try-Catch'able exceptions.  Nothing can be guaranteed in catastrophic situation :)

Comment: You could try it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@After` and `@AfterClass` annotated methods will be executed even if the test fail or a other (not catastrophic) exception occurs. There is only one Exception that skip the execution of the after methods: `OutOfMemoryError` ( `org.apiguardian.api.API.BlacklistedExceptions`).

`@After` and `@AfterClass` are intended for tear down methods, that need to be executed after each/all tests, even if something went wrong.

The code can be found in the method `org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively()`

Answer (score 3):

According to documentation:

- [@After](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/After.html)

> All @After methods are guaranteed to run even if a Before or Test
> method throws an exception

- [@AfterClass](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/index.html?org/junit/AfterClass.html)

> All @AfterClass methods are guaranteed to run even if a BeforeClass
> method throws an exception

`@After` and `@AfterClass` are guaranteed to run.